# Polymer data transfer between different pages of the same application

Tags: polymer

I posted yesterday similar question, but today I discovered how to use data from one page at another page inside the same application. I extended `Page 2` from `Page 1` and now I can use all its properties (of `Page 1`). The problem is that when some property value has changed inside `Page 1` (new value) I still get the old value in `page 2`. How can I reflect the change at Page 1 to the `Page 2`?

Answer (score 1):

For two way data binding from parent to child element and vv.; use `attribute-name = "{{property}}"` (not `[[property]]`) and declare proterty at child as `notify:true` to reflect property upway data binding.

Comment: I used dispatchEvent and window.addEventListener inside callback function to transfer data between pages but it seems I can use that value only inside callback function. Do you have any idea how  to pass that value to already declared property inside the view2??

Comment: I tried to understand your both questions. Sadly, the way of going not so clear. I suggest you try to explain the scenario, then we can make more clear and Polymer way.